# what is the path to Chrome cache on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, ubuntu, caching

I want to be able to clear cache (both browser's own cache and possible offline cache manifests) through the command line.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it better belongs to ubuntu stackexchange or Unix stackexchange sites. I do see however that it's too old to migrate.

Answer (score 16):

Chrome Cache located into Path:

```
$HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/
```

To delete Web browsing Cache:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Cache/
```

To delete video and Music (Media) cache:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Default/Media\ Cache/
```

Also there another `cache` Folder under `Profile 2` Folder:

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/google-chrome/Profile\ 2/Cache/
```

**Notice:** Do not remove all (Folder, Files) under `google-chrome` Folder like this

```
rm -rf $HOME/.cache/google-chrome/
```

Just remove files under Folder and keep Folder Empty.

Answer (score 8):

$HOME/.cache/google-chrome - most likely

Comment: I tried removing that folder entirely and rebooting without internet connection. Everything that was explicitly stored for offline viewing (in offline cache manifests) was still there after removing the suggested DIR. Any thoughts?